# Delete node in a list with passing by reference in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Given the following code for deletion of an element in a doubly linked list:

```
struct list
{
    int info;
    struct list *prev;
    struct list *next;
};

struct list *insert(struct list *top,int k)
{
    struct list *tmp=NULL;
    if(!top)
    {
        tmp=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        if(tmp)
        {
            tmp->info=k;
            tmp->next=NULL;
            tmp->prev=NULL;
            top=tmp;
        }
        else
            printf("error\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        top->next=insert(top->next,k);
        if(top->next)
            top->next->prev=top;
    }
    return top;
}



void delete(struct list **top,int k)
{
    struct list *tmp=NULL;
    if(*top)
    {
        if((*top)->info==k)
        {
            tmp=*top;
            if((*top)->next)
            {
                (*top)->next->prev=(*top)->prev;
            }

            if((*top)->prev)
            {
                (*top)->prev->next=(*top)->next;
            }

            *top=(*top)->next;

            free(tmp);
        }
        else
            delete(&((*top)->next),k);
    }
}
/* correct function
void delete(struct list **top,int k)
{
    struct list *tmp=NULL;
    if(*top)
    {
        if((*top)->info==k)
        {
            tmp=*top;
            if((*top)->next)
            {
                (*top)->next->prev=(*top)->prev;
            }

            if((*top)->prev)
            {
                (*top)->prev->next=(*top)->next;
            }
            else
                *top=(*top)->next;

            free(tmp);
        }
        else
            delete(&((*top)->next),k);
    }
}*/

int main()
{
    int i,k;
    struct list *top=NULL;
    for(i=1;i<11;i++)
       top=insert(top,i);

    printf("insert a key\n");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    delete(&top,k);
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that when the node k is deleted, the field next of the previous node of k does not point to successor of k but to successor of the successor of k.

For example:

Given the following sequence : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

Delete node 5;

Result : 1 2 3 4 7 8 9 10.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**: I added in the comment the function delete in which the pointer advance only when *top is the head, and it works now. But the question is always open, that it, why changing the value of *top is modified also the value of (*top)->prev->next=(*top)->next changed before.

Comment: C is strictly pass by value. It does not support references. Do you mean C++?

Comment: And how do you call this?

Comment: Can you paste the full code..

Comment: Your main function still doesn't tell us anything we didn't already know. Can you include a minimal, verifiable, complete example?

Comment: It's not clear to me the reason why you declare tmp only to free the node and the line  *top=(*top)->next; just after updating the pointers of the surrounding nodes. You are using recursion (why not a loop?) and the advance is performed in the other branch.

Comment: I added the entire code.

Comment: `if((*top)->prev)
            {
                (*top)->prev->next=(*top)->next;
            }

            *top=(*top)->next;` --> `if((*top)->prev) {
    (*top)->prev->next=(*top)->next;
} else {
    *top=(*top)->next;
}`

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/6a6rGt) is working code. You don't have to advance the `top` pointer.

Comment: @callyalater: Thanks for the code.I agree, But why with that row ( *top=(*top)->next;) it does not work?

Comment: I am working on that. Omitting that line causes issues when deleting a node on the end (like `1`).

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/doubly_linked_list_program_in_c.htm) has some code and an explanation for what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working code

I've not checked the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110938/discussion-between-callyalater-and-totoro), but here's my working solution with the test code I used.  It uses an iterative rather than recursive approach.  I didn't change the `insert()` code (though I moved it after the `delete()` function), though I would remove the recursion were it to become 'my' code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{
    int info;
    struct list *prev;
    struct list *next;
};

static
void delete(struct list **top, int k)
{
    struct list *node = *top;
    while (node)
    {
        if (node->info == k)
        {
            if (node->next)
                node->next->prev = node->prev;
            if (node->prev)
                node->prev->next = node->next;
            if (node == *top)
                *top = node->next;
            free(node);
            return;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
}

static
struct list *insert(struct list *top, int k)
{
    struct list *tmp = NULL;
    if (!top)
    {
        tmp = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        if (tmp)
        {
            tmp->info = k;
            tmp->next = NULL;
            tmp->prev = NULL;
            top = tmp;
        }
        else
            printf("error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        top->next = insert(top->next, k);
        if (top->next)
            top->next->prev = top;
    }
    return top;
}

static void dump_list_fwd(const char *tag, struct list *top)
{
    printf("List %p: %s\n", (void *)top, tag);
    while (top != 0)
    {
        printf("  Item %p: %2d (next %p, prev %p)\n", (void *)top,
               top->info, (void *)top->next, (void *)top->prev);
        top = top->next;
    }
}

static void free_list(struct list *top)
{
    while (top != 0)
    {
        struct list *next = top->next;
        free(top);
        top = next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct list *top = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        top = insert(top, i);
    dump_list_fwd("After insert", top);

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        int k = (i * 3 + 5) % 10 + 1;
        printf("Delete %d\n", k);
        delete(&top, k);
        dump_list_fwd("After delete", top);
    }

    free_list(top);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles cleanly using the command line:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror dellink.c -o dellink
```

The functions apart from `main()` are `static` to satisfy the `-Wmissing-prototypes` option.  If the functions were going to be used outside this source file, they'd be declared in a header — but there is no other source file and there is no header, so I made them `static`.

The `delete()` function is rewritten as an iterative function. The key observation (**fix**) is that address stored in the pointer passed to the function should only change when that is the node that is deleted.  This is harder to handle when the code is recursive.  I also avoided using `(*top)` everywhere by copying it into a local variable; that simplifies the code a little.

The print and free functions are straight-forward bits of code. I almost always pass a `tag` string to printing functions so that the different locations where it is called can be simply identified.  Were I doing the job thoroughly, I'd use `uintptr_t` and the `PRIXPTR` macro from `<inttypes.h>` to avoid `0x0` being printed for null pointers (I'd use `"0x%.12" PRIXPTR` to print the addresses, perfectly aware that pointers could need 16 bytes but not often running into that as a problem).

The `main()` code serially adds entries 1..10.  The deleting loop deals with the entries in a different sequence (9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 10, 3, 6) so that the 'remove from start' and 'remove from end' are both executed as well as 'remove from middle'.

#### Sample run

```
List 0x7f9460c03180: After insert
  Item 0x7f9460c03180:  1 (next 0x7f9460c031a0, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c031a0:  2 (next 0x7f9460c031c0, prev 0x7f9460c03180)
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c031e0, prev 0x7f9460c031a0)
  Item 0x7f9460c031e0:  4 (next 0x7f9460c03200, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03200:  5 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x7f9460c031e0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x7f9460c03240, prev 0x7f9460c03200)
  Item 0x7f9460c03240:  7 (next 0x7f9460c03260, prev 0x7f9460c03220)
  Item 0x7f9460c03260:  8 (next 0x7f9460c03280, prev 0x7f9460c03240)
  Item 0x7f9460c03280:  9 (next 0x7f9460c032a0, prev 0x7f9460c03260)
  Item 0x7f9460c032a0: 10 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c03280)
Delete 9
List 0x7f9460c03180: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c03180:  1 (next 0x7f9460c031a0, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c031a0:  2 (next 0x7f9460c031c0, prev 0x7f9460c03180)
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c031e0, prev 0x7f9460c031a0)
  Item 0x7f9460c031e0:  4 (next 0x7f9460c03200, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03200:  5 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x7f9460c031e0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x7f9460c03240, prev 0x7f9460c03200)
  Item 0x7f9460c03240:  7 (next 0x7f9460c03260, prev 0x7f9460c03220)
  Item 0x7f9460c03260:  8 (next 0x7f9460c032a0, prev 0x7f9460c03240)
  Item 0x7f9460c032a0: 10 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c03260)
Delete 2
List 0x7f9460c03180: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c03180:  1 (next 0x7f9460c031c0, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c031e0, prev 0x7f9460c03180)
  Item 0x7f9460c031e0:  4 (next 0x7f9460c03200, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03200:  5 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x7f9460c031e0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x7f9460c03240, prev 0x7f9460c03200)
  Item 0x7f9460c03240:  7 (next 0x7f9460c03260, prev 0x7f9460c03220)
  Item 0x7f9460c03260:  8 (next 0x7f9460c032a0, prev 0x7f9460c03240)
  Item 0x7f9460c032a0: 10 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c03260)
Delete 5
List 0x7f9460c03180: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c03180:  1 (next 0x7f9460c031c0, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c031e0, prev 0x7f9460c03180)
  Item 0x7f9460c031e0:  4 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x7f9460c03240, prev 0x7f9460c031e0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03240:  7 (next 0x7f9460c03260, prev 0x7f9460c03220)
  Item 0x7f9460c03260:  8 (next 0x7f9460c032a0, prev 0x7f9460c03240)
  Item 0x7f9460c032a0: 10 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c03260)
Delete 8
List 0x7f9460c03180: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c03180:  1 (next 0x7f9460c031c0, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c031e0, prev 0x7f9460c03180)
  Item 0x7f9460c031e0:  4 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x7f9460c03240, prev 0x7f9460c031e0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03240:  7 (next 0x7f9460c032a0, prev 0x7f9460c03220)
  Item 0x7f9460c032a0: 10 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c03240)
Delete 1
List 0x7f9460c031c0: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c031e0, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c031e0:  4 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x7f9460c03240, prev 0x7f9460c031e0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03240:  7 (next 0x7f9460c032a0, prev 0x7f9460c03220)
  Item 0x7f9460c032a0: 10 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c03240)
Delete 4
List 0x7f9460c031c0: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x7f9460c03240, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03240:  7 (next 0x7f9460c032a0, prev 0x7f9460c03220)
  Item 0x7f9460c032a0: 10 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c03240)
Delete 7
List 0x7f9460c031c0: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x7f9460c032a0, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
  Item 0x7f9460c032a0: 10 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c03220)
Delete 10
List 0x7f9460c031c0: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c031c0:  3 (next 0x7f9460c03220, prev 0x0)
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x0, prev 0x7f9460c031c0)
Delete 3
List 0x7f9460c03220: After delete
  Item 0x7f9460c03220:  6 (next 0x0, prev 0x0)
Delete 6
List 0x0: After delete
```

The code is given a clean bill of health by [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) — no access errors and no unfreed memory.

### Why does the original code skip a node?

Let's draw a picture — ASCII art to the fore!

#### Before deleting Node 2:

```
  +-----+
  | top |
  +-----+
     |
     v
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
|        |---->|        |---->|        |---->|        |
| Node 1 |     | Node 2 |     | Node 3 |     | Node 4 |
|        |<----|        |<----|        |<----|        |
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

#### Recursive call:

The `top` in the recursive call is actually stored in `'Node 1'->next`!

```
                 +-----+
                 | top |
                 +-----+
                    |
                    v
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
|        |---->|        |---->|        |---->|        |
| Node 1 |     | Node 2 |     | Node 3 |     | Node 4 |
|        |<----|        |<----|        |<----|        |
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

#### Non-null `(*top)->next`:

Assigning: `(*top)->next->prev=(*top)->prev;`

```
                 +-----+
                 | top |
                 +-----+
                    |
                    v
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
|        |---->|        |---->|        |---->|        |
| Node 1 |     | Node 2 |     | Node 3 |     | Node 4 |
|        |<-------------------|        |<----|        |
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

#### Non-null `(*top)->prev`:

Assigning: `(*top)->prev->next=(*top)->next;`

Note that because `top` is actually a pointer to `'Node 1'->next`,
the assignment `(*top)->prev->next = (*top)->next` also changes
`(*top)`.

```
                                +-----+
                                | top |
                                +-----+
                                   |
                                   v
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
|        |------------------->|        |---->|        |
| Node 1 |     | Node 2 |     | Node 3 |     | Node 4 |
|        |<-------------------|        |<----|        |
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

#### Assign `*top` and free

Assigning `(*top) = (*top)->next;`

Because `*top` is also `'Node 1'->next`, the assignment to `*top`
also changes where `'Node 1'->next` points to, skipping `'Node 3'`.
Note that a backwards traverse would still go through `'Node 3'`.

```
                                               +-----+
                                               | top |
                                               +-----+
                                                  |
                                                  v
+--------+                    +--------+     +--------+
|        |---------------------------------->|        |
| Node 1 |                    | Node 3 |     | Node 4 |
|        |<-------------------|        |<----|        |
+--------+                    +--------+     +--------+
```

The reason for the damage is now explained.

Comment: 100K+ rep to the rescue :-)

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Leffler. Do you have some link which explains in details the question of the pointer in the recursive call that you quote? Why when the code i recursive this situation is harder to handle?

Comment: I've added my explanation of what went wrong.  The fix you show (adding a judiciously placed `else` in the `delete()` function) seems to work, and is remarkably neat and tidy.  I've not done enough testing to be more sure than 'seems to work'; I've only run my test program on it, without varying the sequence of deletions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thanks a lot for the detailed reply. The motivation of the wrong is  subtle.